# Got errors in php file require once __DIR__

Tags: php, mysql

I have errors in my php file:

> Warning: require_once(**DIR**/db_connect.php) [function.require-once]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/a6869653/public_html/get_product_details.php on line 11

but I have uploaded the `db_connect.php` in the same directory as the others.

Comment: You forgot your underscores

Comment: Your problem is not `db_connect.php` or its location but rather the way it is included in `get_product_details.php`.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once __DIR__ . DS . 'db_connect.php';
```

or

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
```

should do.

Comment: The underscores are important around the 'DIR' letters, the code is `__DIR__` exactly, as Ashish has shown.

Comment: i already did that but still got errors

Comment: Kindly post the error you are getting after doing the above fix. Also you can try to call some other file in that directory. Please provide the absolute path of the file to be called and the path of the file which has this require code in it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the **DIR** and replace it with require